# Navigating to different views in same window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application that follows MVVM. I am able to design separate windows, but how can I navigate between different views in the same main window instead of launching every view in a different window.
For ex - Consider, I have 2 views. Window1.xaml and Window2.xaml. Consider the third view CommonWindow.xaml. Now, within this CommonWindow.xaml I want to provide a toggle button. When I click this button it should load the Window1 and Window2 alternately within the CommonWindow.xaml.
How can I achieve this? Is there any particular control in WPF that supports this kind of behavior?

Comment: Rather than using a button to toggle between view windows inside of a container window, why not make the view windows controls and put them in a `TabControl` in the common window?

Comment: Can I bind a each tab control to individual View Models?

Comment: No, you have one `TabControl`.  The `TabControl` contains 2 `TabItem`s.  One `TabItem's Content` property is your control for view 1 & the other is your control for view 2.

Comment: Thanks for that. TabControl seems to be a good option. Let me try it out.

Comment: You can use a ContentControl

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a button to toggle between view windows inside of a container window, why not make the view windows controls and put them in a `TabControl` in the common window?  The XAML would look like this:

```
<TabControl>

    <TabItem>
        <local:MyView1>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <local:MyView2>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Looks like exactly, what I needed. This should solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TabControl or Page control for this.

[MVVM-TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/351300/MVVM-TabControl)

[Closeable-TabItems](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/15/WPF-TabControl-series-Part-4-Closeable-TabItems.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the ViewModel to a `ContentControl` and add some DataTemplates for each ViewModel.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SO31437431.View"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SO31437431.ViewModel"
        ...>

    <Grid>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentItem}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:BarViewModel}">
                    <view:BarView/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:FooViewModel}">
                    <view:FooView/>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```